# What is the difference between an ERD and a Context data Model?

Tags: database, database-design, visio, erd

Can someone please gimme an example of both? I am super confused between the two :(

Are they same??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert on the subject but from what I have read it seems that a context diagram is more interested in grouping and relating data based on the context from a user's point of view. So while a client may have an address, name, phone, etc. it will not relate those to the client.  Instead the context diagram will relate the address, name, and phone along with a complaint description, subject, and issue category.

The erd on the other hand is more concerned with how the data is related.  So the client has a 1 to n relationship with complaints and the complaints has a 1 to 1 relationship with descriptions, subjects, and complaint categories.

An erd is probably more useful to a database designer to make sure that the database can support the relationships correctly.

A context diagram (from what I understand) would probably be more useful to a web developer or interface designer so that they can pull the correct data into certain views or forms.